# Playing directshow streams asynchronously into composited output

Tags: c++, directshow, win32gui

I'm a DirectShow newbie. I'm trying to get DirectShow to playback a set of media files but NOT simultaneously.

I've tried allocating one graph and using RendeFile to add each file into it but when I invoke IMediaControl::Run, they ALL begin playing at the same time.

I've tried allocating one graph and one IMediaControl per file and then calling Run at different times on each. This works, the streams play independantly.

How do I combine the streams to an output window?

Is it possible to have a master surface on which the other streams are rendered into rectangles?

Since the streams are not in the same graph, can it be done?

What do I use for a surface or output?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All filters are expected to change state in a graph together, so you indeed need a separate graph for every file you suppose to play back independently from others.

If you are going to play files simply side by side, without effects and overlapping etc., the easiest option is to use separate video renderers and use them as controls, properly positioning them in your UI.

If you instead want something more sophisticated, then there are two ways to choose from: you either take decompressed video/audio out of DirectShow filter graph using Sample Grabber or a similar filter, and then you are responsible for presenting data yourself with other APIs. Or you implement a custom allocator/presented (also known as renderless mode of operation of video renderer) and finely control the output of video, which in particular allows to get a frame into texture or offscreen surface leaving presentation itself to you.